# Understanding 'leftover' from conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit

Why does the following output `[]`?

```
λ: >runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..2] .| leftover 5 .| sinkList
[]
```

I naively expected it to return: `[1,2,5]` per [leftover](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.12.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html)'s docs:

> Provide a single piece of leftover input to be consumed by the next component in the current monadic binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We must make a distinction between the composition of `Conduit`s with `>>=`, and with `.|`.

With `>>=`, we are sequencing the actions of two `Conduit`s that share a common input and a common output stream.

With `.|`, we are connecting the output stream of one `Conduit` to the input stream of another.

The `leftover` function pushes a value into the current position of the current `Conduit`'s input stream, making it available to other `Conduit` actions connected to the same input stream (with `>>=`).  It does not `yield` anything into the current `Conduit`'s output stream, which is why `sinkList` produces the empty list in your example.

If you want to see the effect of `leftover`, you must perform the `sinkList` where it can access the same input stream as the `leftover`:

```
runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..2] .| (leftover 5 >> sinkList)
```

This produces `[5, 1, 2]` (not `[1, 2, 5]`), because the `leftover` pushes the `5` into the input stream before the `1`, and `2`, have been consumed.

If we add an `await` before the `leftover`:

```
runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..2] .| (await >> leftover 5 >> sinkList)
```

then we get `[5, 2]` because we consume (and discard) the `1` before doing the `leftover`.

We could also `yield` from our `leftover` `Conduit`, which will push a value into the output stream to be consumed by another `Conduit` composed with `.|`:

```
runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..2] .| myLeftoverConduit .| sinkList where
  myLeftoverConduit = do
    leftover 5
    l <- sinkList
    yield l
    yield [42]
```

produces `[[5, 1, 2], [42]]` because we `yield`ed the result of `sinkList` (a list), and then `yield`ed `[42]` (also a list).  The downstream `sinkList` then makes a list of these two values.